# XOR binary numbers c#

Tags: c#, binary, xor

I have 2 vars with binary numbers:

```
var bin1 = Convert.ToString(339, 2);
var bin2 = Convert.ToString(45, 2);
```

and I want to XOR them and get a third binary number but the operator ^ doesn't work on them.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Don't XOR binary numbers represented as strings, XOR then as `int`s:

```
var xored = 339 ^ 45;
```

Once operator `^` has done its work, convert the result to `string`:

```
var binXored = Convert.ToString(xored, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by first XOR'ing the two numbers and then converting it to a `string` representation.

```
int n1 = 339;
int n2 = 45;
int n3 = n1 ^ n2;

string b1 = Convert.ToString(n1, 2);
string b2 = Convert.ToString(n2, 2);
string b3 = Convert.ToString(n3, 2);
```